# Why does reinstalling Windows 10 with a recovery drive fail with a Unable to recover-System drive too small message?

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, bios

Pulling my hair trying to fix my son's Lenovo Desktop (Legion Y520T). It started out with him trying to install more ram memory, moving from 1x8GB to 2x16GB. This didn't work, most likely since the PC doesn't support 16GB, so he put the original 8GB back. But then it wouldn't start with the old memory either, getting stuck on a black screen with a *preparing automatic repair* message.

Here I take over trying to reinstall Windows 10 with a recovery drive. Luckily we had an external SSD with a Windows 10 recovery which I created for the same Lenovo and successfully used a few months back.

It took me a while to figure out how to get the PC to load the recovery from USB in the BIOS but after changing the SATA controller settings and some other things it works and I get the initial screens for recovery (chose keyboard layout, then Recover from a Drive, Reinstall Windows from the recovery drive connected to this PC...) so far it seems good.

But when I actually starts the recovery (be it the "just remove my files" or "Fully clean the drive" option) it fails right away with a **Unable to recover - System drive too small** message.

Why is this? What system drive does it refer to (drive in PC or the USB-drive with the recovery image)? Why is it too small now when I did a recovery a few months back on the same PC with the same USB recovery drive?

I hope someone has some hint on what I could try next.

****** **EDIT**  *********

Sorry for not being too clear, I'm not very familiar with HW nomenclature unfortunately. Anyway, I have created a recovery drive [per this instruction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-recovery-drive-abb4691b-5324-6d4a-8766-73fab304c246) so I guess that means *an actual recovery disk* (?)

Yes, we have backups so no need for me to keep anything on the machine, just want to reinstall Windows in any way possible (and recovery disk is the only way I know about).

My $PBR_ResetConfig.xml looks like this:

```
<Reset>
  <SystemDisk>
    <DiskpartScriptPath>$PBR_Diskpart.txt</DiskpartScriptPath>
    <MinSize>906173</MinSize>
    <WindowsREPartition>4</WindowsREPartition>
    <WindowsREPath>Recovery\WindowsRE</WindowsREPath>
    <OSPartition>3</OSPartition>
    <WIMBoot>0</WIMBoot>
    <SingleInstancePPKG>False</SingleInstancePPKG>
  </SystemDisk>
</Reset>
```

With layout of my partitions, do you mean the partitions on the PC (and not on USB drive)? That I don't know since I can't get into the PC.

Comment: Are you using an actual recovery disk or a Windows 10 installation disk?  At this point, I would just reinstall Windows 10 from an installation media.  I assume required backups of personal files have already been taken?  Difficult to know what disk the error message is referring to without more information about the layout of your partitions. On the system restore image, contained within `system image file >> sources >> open the $PBR_ResetConfig.xml` there is a value set for <MinSize> [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Recommended: [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Ensure your USB is large enough and that there is enough free space on the target disk. It's possible that the Windows hard disk is too full to re-install Windows (actually this is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade).

Comment: @harrymc - In-Place upgrade isn't possible with the system in the state it is in

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, you're right, it will need to be a full installation, which requires much more free space, less if the installation will manage to detect the existing Windows installation and do an upgrade instead.

Comment: @harrymc - You cannot perform an upgrade or in-place install from outside of Windows.  So if the only accessible environment is WinRE, only a clean installation will be possible, which will involve deleting partitions (or at least installing Windows over itself which is a very different action than an in-place upgrade).

Comment: According to your edit, create a full boot USB using another PC and install. During the install, choose Advanced, then delete the Windows partition so it becomes unallocated space and install into it. You could also delete all partitions to avoid any leftovers, so the entire disk becomes one unallocated space, and install into this space. With less leftovers, you get maximal disk space.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this instead!